# SQL Error [102] [42000]: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: mysql

```
select customerno,(GETDATE() - date_connected) as days_connected from (
    select customerno, min(ch.connectiondatetime) as  date_connected
    from ConnectionHistory ch
    GROUP by customerno 
    having (GETDATE() - date_connected > 90)
)
```

Comment: sample data and expected output helpful for proper solution

Comment: i want data for  customers that have been connected for over 90 days

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `DATEDIFF` function and `now()` because getdate() is sql server function

```
select customerno,DATEDIFF( date(now()), date(date_connected)) as days_connected from 
    ( 
    select ch.customerno, min(ch.connectiondatetime) as date_connected 
    from ConnectionHistory ch    
    GROUP by customerno 
  having DATEDIFF(date(now()),date(date_connected))>90

    ) as T
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92ff29e/2

Comment: It's giving me an error 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @shonny check now please

Comment: no it doesnot work still giving the same error.am using dbeaver -mysql server